# How to remove the # sign from URLs in an AngularJS application (non .NET) hosted on Azure?

Tags: .net, angularjs, html, azure, gruntjs

I have a situation where I need to update the web.config file on my Azure hosting server. I need to enable html5mode (so I can remove the # sign from my URLs), and so need to make a modification on my server to redirect all requests to index.html. Here is the code that I apparently need to add in the web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

The problem, however, is that there is no web.config. Even though my application is hosted on Azure, it is not a .NET application and was not created using Visual Studio. It is an AngularJS application that was scaffolded using Yeoman, and my tasks are run by Grunt. Here is an image of the structure of my application:

[image]

So, in this case, how would I go about adding the rewrite rule on my server?

Answer (score 0):

As long as `web.config` contains only IIS configuration (`system.webServer` section) it will still be recognized and used if it's hosted by IIS in Azure, even if it's not an ASP.NET application. Just include a `web.config` file in your `app` folder which you are deploying to Azure.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. Assuming I can simply name it as Web.config? Or does it need to have a name based on a certain application?

Comment: It should be named `Web.config`, no matter the application.